# Understanding Recursion for this problem?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is not a question related to a certain problem but I am having a hard time understanding the output and program flow for this problem!

[image]

```js
function one(n) {
  if(n == 1) {
    return
  }

  n--;
  console.log(n);

  return two(one(n), one(n))
}

function two(one, two) {
  console.log(one);
  console.log(two);
}

one(9);
```

First, the output is not really what I think it should be and second I am confused whether when executing line 9, function one(n) which is depicted by 1 will run and exhaust and after that function one(n) which is depicted by 2 will run.....or both will run at the same time (1 and 2)??

Its like 2 functions inside one function.

And why does function two() output n value as undefined instead of a proper decrementing value??

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz added

Comment: `two` logs undefined because it's logging the output of `one`. `one` returns undefined or the output of `two`. `two` also returns undefined.

Comment: "*the output is not really what I think it should be*" - what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused whether when executing line 9, function one(n) which is depicted by 1 will run and exhaust and after that function one(n) which is depicted by 2 will run..

Yes. No two statements execute at the same time in JavaScript.

> And why does function two() output n value as undefined instead of a proper decrementing value?

Because it does output the result of the `one(n)` calls, and the function `one` does not return a value.

Comment: Understood why it returns undefined and as for the first question. What is the order in the the function runs on line 9?

```function one() depicted by 1 runs and exhausts
function one() depicted by 2 runs and exhausts
function two() runs``` ??

Comment: Yes. Arguments are always evaluated before the function call itself. It's the same as `const a = one(n); const b = one(n); two(a, b);`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is returning `undefined` is due to the **break case** in `one()` does not return a value. So calling `two(one(n), one(n));` is like calling `two(undefined, undefined);`